# SQL Query Find an element that meets criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Im working in data base of films for a project, and i need to do a query about finding a film that uses  3 or more songs that were used in another film.
My table follows the next squema:

```
ISAN    IRSC
 1        1
 1        2
 1        3
 2        2
 2        3
 3        4
 4        5
 4        3
 .        .
 .        .
 .        .
```

The ISAN is the code that identifies the film and the IRSC the code that identifies the song.
As an example:

```
ISAN    IRSC
 1        1
```

Means the film which code is one uses the song which code is one.

I would like to know the query i have to execute in Mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the queries that you've tried which did not work so we have a starting point as to where to help?

Comment: *i need to do a query about finding a film that uses 3 or more songs that were used in another film.* Can I say that you need film pairs which have at least 3 common songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ISAN ISAN1, 
       t2.ISAN ISAN2, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IRSC) common_songs_list,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IRSC) common_songs_amount
FROM films t1
JOIN films t2 USING (IRSC)
WHERE t1.ISAN < t2.ISAN 
GROUP BY t1.ISAN, t2.ISAN 
HAVING common_songs_amount >= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks, very much, it was exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Mabe something like this could do the job:

```
select f.ISAN, f.IRSC
from films f
where exists (
  select 1
  from films ff
  where ff.ISAN <> f.ISAN
    and ff.IRSC = f.IRSC
  group by ff.IRSC
  having count(*) >= 3
  )
```

With this query, you are checking in the `exists` that:

1. the films compaired are all different than this one `ff.ISAN <> f.ISAN`
2. and they have the same song than this film `ff.IRSC = f.IRSC`
3. and appears at least in 3 films `count(*) >= 3`

Comment: Thanks @Akina, you were right. About the `distinct`, I don't think it changes the output, I assume there cannot be 2 films with the same `ISAN` and the same `IRSC`

Answer (score 0):

> Im working in data base of films for a project, and i need to do a query about finding a film that uses 3 or more songs that were used in another film.

I interpret this as a film has songs.  Each of those songs has a film-count, which is the number of films the song appears in.  This is asking for films where the film count is greater than 1 on at least three films.  That is equivalently stating that three songs appeared in at least one other film.

I think a self-join is a fine approach.  However, the logic would be:

```
select fs.isan, count(*)
from film_songs fs join
     film_songs fs2
     on fs.isrc = fs2.isrc and
        fs.isan <> fs2.isan
group by fs.isan
having count(distinct isrc) >= 3;
```

If you wanted the list of songs or "other films", you could use `group_concat()`.